# Django REST framework gives 401 to cordova post call for some reason.

Tags: rest, cordova, heroku, sencha-touch, django-rest-framework

I have a very strange problem.

I have a server with Django (on Heroku) and Rest API ([Django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)). I am building HTML app based on Sencha and Cordova.

The problem is that one specific call hangs and does not get returned. Here are a list of facts:

1. Login POST call works, logout calls work
2. GET entries call works and returns entries.
3. However POST call for entry (save or edit) does NOT work.

Here is how the working call looks like:
[image]

And here's how the broken call looks like:
[image]

And here is the Heroku log line on the broken call (gives 401):

```
2014-09-15T09:24:40.305543+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/entries/" host=shpongapp.herokuapp.com request_id=46866f87-a3d4-40f4-b4fb-d5c5289bb8fc fwd="213.91.202.97" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=42ms status=401 bytes=789
```

I am looking for answer/explanation of why this is happening and of course solution on how to get that going. I will post code you want me to.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We figured it out.

First we had to add a new middleware which would display the full error since [REST documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions) states:

`By default all error responses will include a key detail in the body of the response, but other keys may also be included.`

So we printed the full response from Django and got:

`{"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}`

Since DRF by default should exclude CSRF, we remembered to check the settings again and saw that besides the token authentication we had also a SessionAuthentication. So we commented out

`'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',` from the `REST_FRAMEWORK` and the 401 was gone.

As to the, "Why didn't that return to the code at all?", the answer is [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2415) but I won't deal with it.